# Material ui v5 cant customize theme using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add custom color to the theme but i can't access the colors from the pallet via theme.pallete this is my theme section:

```
    import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
    type BackgroundType = {
        background?: string;
        onBackground?: string;
        surface?: string;
        onSurfaceHigh?: string;
        onSurfaceLow?: string;
    };
    type Gradient = {
        main?: string;
        gradientRtl?: string[];
        gradientLtr?: string[];
        gradientDarkRtl?: string[];
        gradientDarkLtr?: string[];
        onGradientLight?: string;
        onGradientDark?: string;
    };
    type meta = {
        inpute?: string;
        inputeActive?: string;
        outlineButton?: string;
        outlineButtonText?: string;
        line?: string;
    };
    
    declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
        export interface PaletteOptions {
            Gradient: Gradient;
            Accent: PaletteOptions["primary"];
            Background: BackgroundType;
            Meta: meta;
        }   
        export interface Palette {
            Gradient: Gradient;
            Accent: PaletteOptions["primary"];
            Background: BackgroundType;
            Meta: meta;
        }
        
        export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
            onLight?: string;
            onDark?: string;
            containerLight?: string;
            containerDark?: string;
            onContainerLight?: string;
            onContainerDark?: string;
            ButtonLight?: string;
            ButtonDark?: string;
            onButtonLight?: string;
            onButtonDark?: string;
        }
    
    const theme = createTheme(
        {
        direction: "rtl",
        typography: {
            fontFamily: [
                "dana",
                "dana-number",
                "Open Sans",
                "Roboto",
                "Arial",
                "-apple-system",
                "BlinkMacSystemFont",
                '"Segoe UI"',
                '"Helvetica Neue"',
                "sans-serif",
                '"Apple Color Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
            ].join(","),
        },
        palette:{
Gradient: {
        main: "#4FC3F7",
        gradientLtr: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        gradientRtl: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        onGradientLight: "#FFFFFF",
        onGradientDark: "#000000",
        gradientDarkRtl: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        gradientDarkLtr: ["#51ABF4", "#4FC3F7"],
    },
    primary: {
        main: "#51ABF4",
        light: "#51ABF4",
        dark: "#51ABF4",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        onDark: "#102231",
        containerLight: "#DCEEFD",
        onContainerLight: "#204462",
        containerDark: "#316792",
        onContainerDark: "#B9DDFB",
    },

    secondary: {
        main: "#4FC3F7",
        light: "#4FC3F7",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#DCF3FD",
        onContainerLight: "#204E63",
        dark: "#4FC3F7",
        onDark: "#102731",
        containerDark: "#2F7594",
        onContainerDark: "#B9E7FC",
    },
    Accent: {
        main: "#9980FF",
        light: "#9980FF",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#EBE6FF",
        onContainerLight: "#3D3366",
        ButtonLight: "#AD99FF",
        onButtonLight: "#FFFFFF",
        dark: "#AD99FF",
        onDark: "#1F1A33",
        containerDark: "#5C4D99",
        onContainerDark: "#D6CCFF",
    },
    error: {
        main: "#DC3545",
        light: "#DC3545",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#F2B5BB",
        onContainerLight: "#58161D",
        ButtonLight: "#E3606D",
        onButtonLight: "#FFFFFF",
        dark: "#E3606D",
        onDark: "#2C0B0E",
        containerDark: "#2C0B0E",
        onContainerDark: "#F1AFB6",
    },
    warning: {
        main: "#EFA82D",
        light: "#EFA82D",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#F9E1B6",
        onContainerLight: "#604312",
        dark: "#F2B957",
        onDark: "#302209",
        containerDark: "#8F651B",
        onContainerDark: "#F9DCAB",
    },
    success: {
        main: "#28AB46",
        light: "#28AB46",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#ACEBBB",
        onContainerLight: "#08220E",
        dark: "#53BC6B",
        onDark: "#08220E",
        containerDark: "#18672A",
        onContainerDark: "#A9DDB5",
    },
    Background: {
        background: "#F5F8FC",
        onBackground: "#61666B",
        surface: "#FFFFFF",
        onSurfaceHigh: "#4E5256",
        onSurfaceLow: "#818589",
    },
    Meta: {
  inpute:"#A0A3A6",
  inputeActive:"#61666B",
  outlineButton:"#A0A3A6",
  outlineButtonText:"#61666B",
  line:"#DFE0E1"
},
    
    
    });
     
    export default theme;
    
    
        
    }
```

I declared a module on @mui/material/styles but it seems that it is not working cuz when I m trying to access to for example accent palette option I get the there is no option error even I can't access it from autocomplete from my vs code. I'm just doing what docs say am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but its a little bit strange after i declared palette as an object and pass it to a theme instead of writing inside theme directly it recognized

```
const MyPalete={
    Gradient: {
        main: "#4FC3F7",
        gradientLtr: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        gradientRtl: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        onGradientLight: "#FFFFFF",
        onGradientDark: "#000000",
        gradientDarkRtl: ["#4FC3F7", "#51ABF4"],
        gradientDarkLtr: ["#51ABF4", "#4FC3F7"],
    },
    primary: {
        main: "#51ABF4",
        light: "#51ABF4",
        dark: "#51ABF4",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        onDark: "#102231",
        containerLight: "#DCEEFD",
        onContainerLight: "#204462",
        containerDark: "#316792",
        onContainerDark: "#B9DDFB",
    },

    secondary: {
        main: "#4FC3F7",
        light: "#4FC3F7",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#DCF3FD",
        onContainerLight: "#204E63",
        dark: "#4FC3F7",
        onDark: "#102731",
        containerDark: "#2F7594",
        onContainerDark: "#B9E7FC",
    },
    Accent: {
        main: "#9980FF",
        light: "#9980FF",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#EBE6FF",
        onContainerLight: "#3D3366",
        ButtonLight: "#AD99FF",
        onButtonLight: "#FFFFFF",
        dark: "#AD99FF",
        onDark: "#1F1A33",
        containerDark: "#5C4D99",
        onContainerDark: "#D6CCFF",
    },
    error: {
        main: "#DC3545",
        light: "#DC3545",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#F2B5BB",
        onContainerLight: "#58161D",
        ButtonLight: "#E3606D",
        onButtonLight: "#FFFFFF",
        dark: "#E3606D",
        onDark: "#2C0B0E",
        containerDark: "#2C0B0E",
        onContainerDark: "#F1AFB6",
    },
    warning: {
        main: "#EFA82D",
        light: "#EFA82D",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#F9E1B6",
        onContainerLight: "#604312",
        dark: "#F2B957",
        onDark: "#302209",
        containerDark: "#8F651B",
        onContainerDark: "#F9DCAB",
    },
    success: {
        main: "#28AB46",
        light: "#28AB46",
        onLight: "#FFFFFF",
        contrastText: "#FFFFFF",
        containerLight: "#ACEBBB",
        onContainerLight: "#08220E",
        dark: "#53BC6B",
        onDark: "#08220E",
        containerDark: "#18672A",
        onContainerDark: "#A9DDB5",
    },
    Background: {
        background: "#F5F8FC",
        onBackground: "#61666B",
        surface: "#FFFFFF",
        onSurfaceHigh: "#4E5256",
        onSurfaceLow: "#818589",
    },
    Meta: {
  inpute:"#A0A3A6",
  inputeActive:"#61666B",
  outlineButton:"#A0A3A6",
  outlineButtonText:"#61666B",
  line:"#DFE0E1"
},
};



const theme = createTheme(
    {
    direction: "rtl",
    typography: {
        fontFamily: [
            "dana",
            "dana-number",
            "Open Sans",
            "Roboto",
            "Arial",
            "-apple-system",
            "BlinkMacSystemFont",
            '"Segoe UI"',
            '"Helvetica Neue"',
            "sans-serif",
            '"Apple Color Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
            '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
        ].join(","),
    },
    palette:MyPalete


});
 
export default theme;
```

but I don't know what is differs on writing directly and taking a palette to an object and passing